# Use Enthought Canopy to run a python script without specifying its full path

Tags: python, python-2.7, enthought, canopy

I want to be able to run a python script at the command line using Enthought Canopy, but I don't want to specify the full path to the script.

As I see it, there are two options.

Option 1: Make the python script an executable, add `#!/usr/bin/env python` to the top of the script, and put the directory containing the script on my `$PATH`.  Now I can execute the script like this:

```
$ run.py
```

Option 2: As suggested by Andrew Clark in another [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10002291/how-to-run-a-python-script-portably-without-specifying-its-full-path), just put the directory containing the script on my `$PYTHONPATH`.  Then I can execute the script like this:

```
$ python -m run.py
```

The `-m` causes python to search the `$PYTHONPATH`.

I prefer Option 2, and it works fine with the system python on my mac (v2.7.2), but I cannot get it to work with Enthought Canopy.  I can load Canopy python and import modules in the same directory as `run.py`, so I know that I have the path correct.  I just cannot execute the script from the command line.  Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BTW, it's probably a typo, but just to make sure you should be using the module name, not the file name, with the `-m` option.  For example, `python -m run`

If that is not the problem then make sure that the python that is used in your option 2 is the python located in your Canopy User virtual environment.  You can use the `which` command to verify that.  For example:

`$ which python
/Users/YourUserId/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/python`

If that is not what you get then you can either add that bin folder to the beginning of your `PATH` environment variable, or you can activate that virtual environment like this:

`source /Users/YourUserId/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/activate`

Comment: for more description of this see https://support.enthought.com/entries/23646538-Make-Canopy-User-Python-be-your-default-Python

Comment: The "typo" was the problem.  I did not realize that I should have been using `python -m run` and not `python -m run.py`.  Thanks for the help!